# Most strategic method of two step collection fetching?

Tags: backbone.js, collections

The way the API im using handles collections is as follows. Lets call it users:

1. /users return an array of user ID's. Then to get the actual users, you do:
2. /user/id

What would be the most strategic method of populating a collections?

I was thinking to set the collection url to /users , and then call /user/id in the parse method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would generally have a **Model** associated to the **Collection**.

```
Var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
     idAttribute : 'id'
});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model : User,
     url : '/users'
});

var user = new User();
var users = new Users();
```

So if you want to get the list of users. You would do a collections.fetch();

```
users.fetch();  // in this case
```

Similarly, if you want to get a single user based on the `id` of user.

You can set the **`urlRoot`** property on the **Model**

```
 Var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
     idAttribute : 'id',
     urlRoot : '/user'
 });
 var user = new User();
 user.fecth()
```

The `id` will by default be the last parameter appended to the url when a request is made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had the right idea about using the `parse` method:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/user',
    // idAttribute: 'id', // This is the default
    initialize: function() {
        // If you need the info right away, do this
        // Otherwise I would probably just fetch when necessary
        this.fetch();
    }
});
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model : User,
   url : '/users',
   parse: function(response) {
       // Assuming the response is just an array like [1,2,3,4]
       return _.map(response, function(id) { return { id: id }; });
   }
});

var users = new Users();
users.fetch();
```